# Extra characters...?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So, basically. What I'm trying to do is create a word unscrambler, where you put in a scrambled word and unscrambles it. It works fine, although I check each character individually, for some reason extra characters slip through.

I'd enter `"olehl (hello)"`, it would return `"dhole, haole, helio, hello, helos, helot, holed, holes, holey, hosel, hotel, hovel, hoyle, mohel, sheol, thole, whole"`. I don't know how the things like `"mohel"` and `"dhole"` got in there.

My code:

```
function unscramble(word) {
    var words = require("an-array-of-english-words");

    var matched = [];

    words.forEach((x) => {
        if(word.length != x.length) {

        } else {
            if(matched.length == 42) return;

            var newword = word.split('');

            var added = 0;

            var i = 0;

            for(i = 0; i <= newword.length-1; i++) {
                if(x.indexOf(newword[i]) >= 0) added++; 

                if(i == word.length-1 && added == word.length && added == x.length) matched.push(x);
            }

        }
    });

    return matched;
}
```

Comment: You need to debug it. Go through the code line by line with a debugger or print statements, and find out where the extra characters are being inserted.

Comment: I have, the "newword" string never changes.

Comment: Well, they're getting in somewhere. You'll need to go through it again. Watch the line with `matched.push`, and wait until a word with a bad character is added, then figure out where that word came from.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Also, please note the part about writing a good title. Your current title is meaningless.

Comment: `dhole` matches `h`, `e`, `l twice` and `o` - that's 5 matches - perhaps you need to "remove" matched characters from the target once they are matched ... P.S. I picked dhole example because it's funny

Comment: Just curious, but why are you limiting your `matched` array to 42 items?

Answer (score 1):

`x.indexOf(newword[i])` can still be true even if x contains a character that `newword` does not. So `hello` can still match `dhole` because they are the same length and the `l` matches twice. If you only want it to match `hello` and not something like `heloo` (same letters in different amounts) you also need to keep track of which letters are consumed.

There are a lot of ways that you could do this, but one would be actually remove found letters from `x`.

```
const idx = x.indexOf(newword[i]);
if (-1 !== idx) {
  added++;
  // remove this character
  // You will have to keep track of the original length of `x` as well
  x = x.substring(0, idx) + x.substring(idx + 1, x.length); 
}
```

You could also sort `x` and `newword` and compare the resulting strings/arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Explosion Pills. How about something like the following (not js, just an outline)?

```
function unscramble(word)
  var dictionary = some_array_of_words
  var matches = []
  var sortedWord = word.split('').sort().join('') // sort the word

  dictionary.forEach(dictionaryWord) {
    if (sortedWord.length == dictionaryWord.length) {
      sortedDictionaryWord = dictionaryWord.split('').sort().join('')
      if sortedWord == sortedDictionaryWord {
        matches.push (dictionaryWord)
      }
    }
  }
  return matches
}
```